# Rogue AP channel hopping problem

Tags: networking, wifi, kali-linux, access-point

I am able to set AP but despite explicitly setting channel for monitor interface and AP, AP frequency changes regularly.

My setup:

- OS: Kali Linux 1.0 (booted from a USB stick)
- External network adapter: Alfa AWUS036NH (chipset Ralink RT2870/3070, driver:
  rt2800usb)
- On-board network adapter: Atheros (chipset AR9485, driver:
  ath9k)

What I want to achieve:

- to create an AP which runs on channel 6 on the Alfa adapter

What I've done:

```
root@kali:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr dc:0e:a1:28:8f:fc  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:480 (480.0 B)  TX bytes:480 (480.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9c:b7:0d:04:d2:f5  
          inet addr:192.168.2.140  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::9eb7:dff:fe04:d2f5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:105 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:29 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:11692 (11.4 KiB)  TX bytes:2834 (2.7 KiB)

wlan3     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:c0:ca:59:23:d0  
          inet addr:192.168.2.223  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2c0:caff:fe59:23d0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:21 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1572 (1.5 KiB)  TX bytes:1300 (1.2 KiB)

root@kali:~# iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan3     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"SomeNetwork"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 0A:60:6E:EA:96:31   
          Bit Rate=13 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-27 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:2   Missed beacon:0

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"SomeNetwork"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 0A:60:6E:EA:96:31   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-39 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:2  Invalid misc:25   Missed beacon:0

root@kali:~# ifconfig wlan3 down
root@kali:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr dc:0e:a1:28:8f:fc  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:480 (480.0 B)  TX bytes:480 (480.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9c:b7:0d:04:d2:f5  
          inet addr:192.168.2.140  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::9eb7:dff:fe04:d2f5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:125 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:29 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:15214 (14.8 KiB)  TX bytes:2834 (2.7 KiB)

root@kali:~# iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan3     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"SomeNetwork"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 0A:60:6E:EA:96:31   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-38 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:2  Invalid misc:25   Missed beacon:0

root@kali:~# airmon-ng check kill


Found 4 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!
-e 
PID Name
3512    NetworkManager
3620    wpa_supplicant
3849    dhclient
4263    dhclient
Process with PID 4263 (dhclient) is running on interface wlan3
Process with PID 3849 (dhclient) is running on interface wlan0
Killing all those processes...
root@kali:~# airmon-ng check kill
root@kali:~# ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:720 (720.0 B)  TX bytes:720 (720.0 B)

root@kali:~# iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan3     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

root@kali:~# iwconfig wlan3 channel 6
root@kali:~# airmon-ng start wlan3 6


Interface   Chipset     Driver

wlan3       Ralink RT2870/3070  rt2800usb - [phy1]
                (monitor mode enabled on mon0)
wlan0       Atheros AR9485  ath9k - [phy0]

root@kali:~# airbase-ng -c 6 -e FreeWiFi mon0
15:04:22  Created tap interface at0
15:04:22  Trying to set MTU on at0 to 1500
15:04:22  Trying to set MTU on mon0 to 1800
15:04:22  Access Point with BSSID 00:C0:CA:59:23:D0 started.
```

In the other terminal window I was running airodum-ng on mon0 and could see that channel hopping would be occuring (CH value x would be changing constantly):

```
BSSID    PWR  Beacons    #Data, #/s  CH  MB   ENC  CIPHER AUTH  ESSID
00:C0:CA:59:23:D0    0     2969        0    0   x  54   OPN              FreeWiFi
```

I haven't put at0 interface up neither run dhcp service but I believe that is not important at this stage.

On another Android device I've been running WiFi Analyzer app which confirms that my rogue AP "FreeWiFi" does channel hopping.

Questions:

1) **Why does channel hopping occur despite I set channel to 6 for wlan3, mon0 and also for AP?**

2) How to make my AP working on a fixed channel?

Please let me know if any additional info is needed in order to analyze this behaviour.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart To be honest, I don't remember. I was doing some hobby experiments and this problem might have gone out of my radar after some time. But if I did, I would have posted the solution here. If I get some spare time, I'll try to recreate this environment and see if I can get this working.

Comment: No worries, I have atheros and ralink cards. I was going to try and help you / resolve the question.

Comment: If you crack on with this and find the solution, it would be good to post it here for other readers :)